# Math functions in 2 table column using a Trigger MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to do delegate some of my application logic to the database so as to learn a few items e.g triggers

I have 3 columns called **item_quantity, items_committed** and **items_available**. Basically if there are 5 items in the quantity column and a user commits 2 items, then the items available are 3. I need a trigger that does the minus function of the 2 columns(**quantity** and **committed**) whenever either column is updated and updates the result of the difference in the available column of that row

Below is the trigger I am using but I get this error **'SQL Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'items_available'**

```
CREATE trigger `test`.`trigger_updateitems_available` AFTER UPDATE ON items FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET items_available = item_quantity - items_Committed;

END
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To specify that you want to access the value of the current row, use `new.<field name>`.
Also, to access `new` you need the trigger to be `BEFORE UPDATE`.

```
CREATE trigger `test`.`trigger_updateitems_available` BEFORE UPDATE ON items FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET new.items_available = new.item_quantity - new.items_Committed;

END
```